# Showing that functional composition of a function is close

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For a fixed point  $\big(a,b\big)$  in$ R^{2}$ 
define  $T_{a,b} :R^{2} \rightarrow R^{2} by  \big(x,y\big)  \rightarrow  \big(x+a,y+b\big).$

then $ G= \big\{T_{a,b}| a,b \in R\big\}$ is a group under functional composition. 
How do I show $T_{a,b}T_{c,d}=T_{a+c,b+d}$?

Looking for a vital **clue** to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should prove $T_{a,b}\circ T_{c,d}=T_{a+c,b+d}$ in the functional sense. That is $T_{a,b}\circ T_{c,d}(x,y)=T_{a+c,b+d}(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

But $T_{a,b}\circ T_{c,d}(x,y)=T_{a,b}(T_{c,d}(x,y))=T_{a,b}(x+c,y+d)=(x+c+a,x+d+b)$ which clearly is equal to $T_{a+c,b+d}(x,y)$.